# Property returning as a property object, not it's getter, in isinstance evaluation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm checking if the instance of a property is of a certain type, but in that evaluation it's returning as a property object, not the getter that I have assigned to it.

Other answers to similar questions suggest that it could be because the getter uses something that isn't defined yet, but as far as I can tell everything is already defined.

Definition:

```
class SceneController():

    ...

    def get_scene(self):
        if self._current_level_name is not None and self._current_level_name in self._scene_stack:
            return self._scene_stack[self._current_level_name]
        else:
            return None


scene_control = SceneController()

@property
def scene():
    return scene_control.get_scene()
```

Failing usage:

```
# Prints <class 'property'>
print(type(scene))

# This fails
if isinstance(scene, GameScene):
    ...
```

Comment: properties only work inside classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, `property()` is a built-in function which creates and returns a property object.

The signature of this function is:
`property(fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None)`.

fget is getter, fset is setter and fdel is deleter attributes of property.

When you write a property like:

`@property
 def foo():
     return 'something'`

it is internally mapped to `foo=property(foo)`. And the returned value is a property object.

You can check it by `isinstance(foo, property)`. It will return True.

For more details, follow [property in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).

Comment: I didn't know about that internal mapping, very cool, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
if isinstance(scene(), GameScene)
    ...
```

Because you are comparing a `@property` decorated function to the type of an instance of whatever you return from `get_scene`. I am assuming `self._scene_stack[...]` is of `GameScene`.

You should be careful when using the `@property` decorator, because it is a **special decorator** in that it provides extra properties (just try typing in  `property().getter`). By nature, decorators like:

```
@foo
def bar():
    ...
```

Does essentially `foo(bar())`, so I'm not sure if that's your actual use case for the decorator in the first place.

Comment: This is helpful in understanding properties, though adding the parenthesis results in a "property is not callable error".

Comment: Yes, because it's a property. The associated `.getter`, `.setter` decorators must be declared and then you can do things like `scene = foo` for `.setter` decorated functions, and `foo = scene` for `.getter` decorated functions. A property is not a callable entity.

Comment: In this case does code block in which I decorate def scene() with @property not define the getter?